# ListView cannot get height. ImageView image is height uncertain

Tags: android, listview, imageview, height

Imageview is from the web image, his height is scaled with the width

ImageView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_intro_img"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/product_top"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/lv_intro"
            android:divider="@null"></ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Set the ListView height

```
public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView, int basicsHeight,int plusItem) {
    int totalHeight = basicsHeight;
    ListAdapter adapter = listView.getAdapter();

    for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View listItem = adapter.getView(i, null, listView);
        listItem.measure(0, 0);
        int itemheight=listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        Log.e("ItemView"+i, "height" + itemheight);
        totalHeight += itemheight + plusItem;
    }
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (adapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```

But this log has been printing height 0，

I think about it again,Add an ImageView listen event, but still get nothing
I still can't get the ImageView height

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.product_item_intro, null);
        iv_intro_img = convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_intro_img);
    }
    String imgurl = datas.get(position); //+ "_500x500.jpg";
    RequestOptions myOptions = new RequestOptions()
        .fitCenter();

    Glide.with(mContext).load(imgurl).apply(myOptions).into(iv_intro_img);

    iv_intro_img.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int itemtHeight = iv_intro_img.getHeight();
            int itemtHeight2= iv_intro_img.getMeasuredHeight();
            Log.e("itemimageview" + position, "height" + itemtHeight + "," + itemtHeight2);
            iv_intro_img.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}
```

But not yet. I hope you can help me set ListView height.

Answer (score 0):

try this   It`s Worked For me

**List    Is Your Adapter Data**

**lvMedical    Is Your ListView**

```
   int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, lvMedical);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = lvMedical.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (lvMedical.getDividerHeight() * (lvMedical.getCount() - 1));
        lvMedical.setLayoutParams(params);
        lvMedical.requestLayout();
```

Comment: When you execute this method, Image is still loading, and you can not get the current height.

Comment: listItem.getMeasuredHeight(); Its value is always 0

Comment: Make Your ImageView Height Fixed  , Cause You have to wait loading All Pictures First !

Comment: If the picture is highly fixed, then the image is not good, I am loading the network picture, it is not the same height, I tried to call the picture after loading the height, but it seems to have nothing to use.

Comment: `iv_intro_img.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int itemtHeight = iv_intro_img.getHeight();
            int itemtHeight2= iv_intro_img.getMeasuredHeight();
            Log.e("itemimageview" + position, "height" + itemtHeight + "," + itemtHeight2);
            iv_intro_img.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });`